# Problems Installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to install SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with SP1, and am failing the "Operating system supported for edition" operation in the Installation Rules portion of the install. Can anyone shed some insight into why I'm failing this? As far as I can tell, the version of SQL Server is compatible with the version of Windows Server I'm attempting to install it on. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Here's a link to a screenshot: http://i45.tinypic.com/4j12ye.jpg

Comment: Right. It would be advantageous to click on "view detailed report" don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of known issues with installing SQL Server 2008 RTM on Windows 2008R2. This Microsoft knowledgebase article explains them in reasonable detail:

> [List of known issues when you install SQL Server on Windows 7 or on Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955725)

As MDMarra suggested in his comment to you it would be useful to see what the "detailed report" says, but my money would be on either that the .NET Framework 3.5 isn't enabled or you'll maybe need to slipstream SQL 2008 SP1 into your SQL 2008 install disk/ISO.